# Custom training with my own images using tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to tensorflow and I have trouble with feeding my custom data to keras model.

I've followed this guide:[Load images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) to convert my .jpg files to tf.data.

Now I have my data converted to (image_batch, label_batch). The image_batch is EagerTensor with shape (32,224,224,3) and the label_batch is EagerTensor with shape (32,2).

Then I found this guide:[Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough) but the data in the guild is converted to EagerTensor with shape (32,4).

I got Warning when executing the code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(3,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

```
predictions = model(image_batch)
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 3) for input Tensor("dense_input:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 224, 224, 3).
```

How should I adjust my model or what should I do with my data?

### EDIT:

The model now works, but with one additional problem.

When I run the following code:

```
print("Prediction: {}".format(tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1)))
print("    Labels: {}".format(labels_batch))
```

it prints:

```
Prediction: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
    Labels: [[ True False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]...(omitted)]
```

But I expected it prints something like:

```
Prediction: [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
    Labels: [2 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 2 2 0 2]
```

with Labels as a one dimensional array with integers.

I wonder if it is normal that the predictions are all 1? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is 32 images of shape (224, 224, 3) not (3,). Your input shape needs to be (224,224,3).

I am also noting that your output shape looks like it is going to be (224,224,3) as well, this won't match your labels. You need to flatten the data at some point or do something similar.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(224,224,3)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.kears.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
```

Comment: Now I got another problem, could you help me out?

Comment: Why would you expect to have 0, 1, and 2 in your labels. You said your labels was dimension (32,2). It looks like your labels may be OneHotEncoded. Try writing "labels_batch[:,1].astype('int')".

Comment: Atfer replacing `labels_batch` with `labels_batch[:,1].astype('int')` , I got an error: `AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'astype'`. And no, I meant I expect to see a one dimensional array with 0 or 1 instead of many true or false. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You wrote, print("    Labels: {}".format(labels_batch)), which I took to mean that your variable was a numpy array and you were trying to display the data. Your error suggests something else. At this point I am confused about how you are using your variables, it would probably be best to have a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

The input shape to the Danse layer should have a dimension (None, n), where None is a `batch_size`. In your case, if you'd like to use a Dense layer you should first use a `Flatten` layer wich roll your images to the shape `(32, 224 * 224 * 3)`. The code should be:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

For more details please see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten

Comment: The Dense layer works with arbitrary dimensions and only applies to the last axis. You don't have to Flatten() before using a Dense layer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but you have to use a Flatten layer before putting the image of the shape (None, 224, 224,3)  to train your network on the all pixels from the image.

Comment: Well, I think that is a matter of opinion if you want to cast the Dense layer to each of the axes, or create one giant Dense layer. Different data will obviously perform better/worse depending on which you want to do. In any case we are clearly in agreement that Flatten() needs to exist somewhere (or equivalent).